# How can I optimise this to run in an efficient manner?

Tags: c++, algorithm

The link for the question is as follows: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/478/C

You have r red, g green and b blue balloons. To decorate a single table for the banquet you need exactly three balloons. Three balloons attached to some table shouldn't have the same color. What maximum number t of tables can be decorated if we know number of balloons of each color?

Your task is to write a program that for given values r, g and b will find the maximum number t of tables, that can be decorated in the required manner.

Input:
The single line contains three integers r, g and b (0 ≤ r, g, b ≤ 2·10^9) — the number of red, green and blue baloons respectively. The numbers are separated by exactly one space.

Output:
Print a single integer t — the maximum number of tables that can be decorated in the required manner.

So, what I did was, in a greedy manner, searched for the maximum and minimum value each time and subtracted 2 and 1 respectively if possible. Here is my code:

```
int main (void)
{
    int ans=0,r,g,b;
    cin>>r>>g>>b;
    while (1)
    {
        int a1 = maxfind(r,g,b);
        int a2 = minfind(r,g,b);
        //ans++;
        if (a1 >= 2 && a2 >= 1)
        {
            ans++;
            if (indma == 1)
                r = r-2;
            else if (indma == 2)
                g = g-2;
            else 
                b = b-2;
            if (indmi == 1)
                r = r-1;
            else if (indmi == 2)
                g = g-1;
            else
                b = b-1;
        }
        else if (r == 1 && g == 1 && b == 1)
        {
            ans++;
            break;
        }
        else
            break;

    }
    cout<<ans<<"\n";

int maxfind(int r, int g, int b)
{
    indma = 0;
    int temp = INT_MIN;
    if (r >= temp)
    {
        temp = r;
        indma = 1;
    }
    if (g >= temp)
    {
        temp = g;
        indma = 2;
    }
    if (b >= temp)
    {
        temp = b;
        indma = 3;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Similar is the function for `findmin` and I make sure that it's not the same number chosen in case the maximum and minimum values are same. However, since the limit is 2*10^9, obviously, this surpasses the Time limit. How can I optimise it? Thanks!

Edit: You can easily find sample test cases in the link for the question. However, I am still adding one of them.

```
Input
5 4 3
output
4
```

Explanation: In the first sample you can decorate the tables with the following balloon sets: "rgg", "gbb", "brr", "rrg", where "r", "g" and "b" represent the red, green and blue balls, respectively.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Does each table end up with a red balloon, a green balloon and a blue balloon, so that the number of tables is simply min(r,min(b,g))?

Comment: Can you describe your algorithm? If it takes 3 balloons for a table, and they should have different colors, then isn't `t = min(r, g, b)`?

Comment: You do not need anything except one condition and simple arithmetic to solve this problem. Certainly not loops.

Comment: @TonyRuth: A table must be decorated using exactly three balloons of either two or three different colors.

Comment: I have added the link and the sample test cases.

Comment: @Jon, that's amazing to know. But, I feel bad that I have not been able to come up with it in the first place on my own if it is simple.

Comment: @rohansingh: There is certainly no need to feel bad, although the "failure"  can serve as motivation for some people. But here's a tip: whenever they tell you the input can go into the billions, this is code for "do not even think about using a straight loop for this".

Comment: @Jon, yes correct. I will keep this in mind from next time onwards. :)

Comment: A question for the community, why my question has been down voted? Is it because it was wrongly framed? How can I improve myself in the future?

Comment: Shouldn't this have a closed-form solution?

Comment: @rohansingh I didn't downvote, but if I did it would be because it's a question about an algorithm obscured by lots of irrelevant code.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz, if I wouldn't have included my code, people would have said that it's a homework question, and I should do it on my own. I was just trying to show my attempt for this.

Comment: @rohansingh You just explain your algorithm and make it clear that you're specifically asking for help improving the algorithm. Anyone who criticizes you for not writing code before you have an algorithm you're happy with is crazy. (And I might be wrong about why people are downvoting.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split this problem into two scenarios, either you use all the balloons(with 0, 1, or 2 left over), or you don't because there is too many of one color and not enough of the other two.

If you use all the balloons, the answer is simply (r+g+b)/3

if you don't use all the balloons, then the answer is equal to the sum of the lower 2 of the three numbers.

```
t = min((r+g+b)/3,r+g+b-max(r,g,b))
```

Comment: Nope. What if the numbers are (0, 2, 3)? The answer is definitely not 2.

Comment: min((r+g+b)/3 = 1, r+g+b-max(r,g,b) = 2) = 1

Comment: @yzt His algorithm doesn't give 2, it gives 1. So no problem there.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes, but his code and description don't match.

Comment: @yzt How do you figure? min(1,2) is 1.

Comment: @yzt I think the phrase use all the balloons is what is confusing, I tried to clarify.

Comment: How about (0, 9, 10)? The answer is 5, I think, but the algorithm proposed here gives 6.

Comment: @TonyRuth, just a clarification their. I got the part when you simply did `(r+g+b)/3` and also when you take the lower two values avoiding the maximum value, but in the end, why do you take the minimum of the two? We have to print the maximum we can make, right? So, shouldn't it be max of the two scenarios? Thanks!

Comment: @rohansingh No. Say you want to drive to Denver, or as far as possible as you can get on the gas you have. You want to drive as much possible, but you have a constraint, you may run out of gas. So the distance you can drive is the minimum of how far you get if you have no constraint (all the way to Denver) and how far your gas can take you. The first is how far you get if the constraint doesn't limit you. The second is how far you can get limited by only the constraint. There are two stopping conditions (no balloons, wrong balloons) and you have to stop if you hit either.

Comment: @rohansingh , the reason is because if one scenario works, the other makes no sense. In the first case I am assuming you have enough of the 2nd and 3rd largest number to use all of the 1st largest number of balloons. In the second case I am assuming that the largest number is more than twice the sum of the smaller two numbers. Each only works in its own domain where it is the smaller of the two answers.

Comment: @TonyRuth, though the intuition for this is settling in, but can you edit your answer for this fact: `In the second case I am assuming that the largest number is more than twice the sum of the smaller two numbers.` How did you arrive on this mathematical point?

Comment: @rohansign ,  No table can have more than 2 balloons of the same color, and so in the second scenario all the tables have 2 balloons of whichever color is greatest, and 1 balloon from the remaining colors. The dividing line is when 2*max = the other two combined.

Comment: @yzt with (0, 9, 10) you can do 4 * (0,1,2) + 2 * (0,2,1)

Comment: I think you have found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the problem but just at your code:

If the smallest number is less than the middle number and at least two less than the largest number before any iteration then this is true after that iteration as well (because the smallest number will now be less than the number that was the largest, and it will be two less than the number that was the middle one). In that case you can figure out exactly what will happen throughout your algorithm (the largest number will be decreased by two until it is not the largest anymore, and then the two largest numbers will be decreased by two in turn). So you can figure out exactly what ans will be without actually doing all the iterations.

If the two smallest numbers are equal and the largest is at least three larger then in the next two iterations both smallest numbers will be decreased by 1 once, while the largest will be decreased by 2 twice. You can calculate how often that happens.

After that you end up with (x, x+1, x+1), (x, x, x+2), (x, x, x+1) or (x, x, x). Here you can also predict what will happen in the next iteration or the next two iterations. It's a bit complicated, but not very complicated. For example, if three numbers are (x, x, x+1) then the next three numbers will be (x-1, x, x-1) which is the same pattern again.

Example: Start with (10^9, 10^9 + 1, 10^9 + 1000): You will 500 times subtract 1 from the first and 2 from the last number, giving (10^9 - 500, 10^9 + 1, 10^9 + 0). Then you will 10^9 - 500 times decrease the first number by 1, and since the number is even you will decrease each of the other two numbers by two (10^9 - 500) / 2 times. At that point you have (0, 501, 500) and your algorithm ends with ans = 10^9.

Now this shows how to do the calculation in constant time. It doesn't show whether this gives the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I optimise this to run in an efficient manner?

By looking at the problem more closely. The brute force approach will not work (unfortunately).

Fortunately, the numbers can be calculated in a single closed equation without resorting to recursion or looping.

Let's try a derivation: You start with `(r, g, b)` balloons.  The upper limit of tables is certainly `sum(r, g, b) / 3` (integer division, i.e. round down) because you need at least three times as many balloons as tables.

What about the less than-optimal cases? To decorate a table, you need two balloons of different colors but you do not care about the color of the third one.

Let's assume that you have fewest green (`min(r, b, g) = g`) balloons. So you can certainly decorate `g` tables as long as you have enough baloons in total (already covered). How many more tables can you decorate?

Assuming you did not use up all balloons yet (i.e. `g < sum(r, b, g) / 3`) you have used up `2 x g` balloons of the other colors, i.e. you have a total of `sum(r, b) - 2 x g` balloons left. This can be an arbitrary combination of the available red and blue balloons since we can shuffle them around as we like.

If we assume, that the red (`r`) balloons are the second least frequent (i.e. most balloons are blue), we can decorate at most `min(r, sum(r, b) - 2 x g)` more tables. We either run out of red balloons or we run out of balloons, whichever one happens first.

Since we already covered the case of running out of balloons, we can ignore the second term of `min(r, sum(r, b) - 2 x g)`.

So indeed, the number of tables is `min(sum(r, b, g) / 3, min(r + b, r + g, b + g))` or simplified `min(sum(r, b, g) / 3, sum(r, b, g) - max(r, b, g))`, or, colloquially, the minimum of a third of the total number and the sum of the two least frequent colors.